# Python locust tasks are blocked when used with pyodbc

Tags: python, sql-server, database, postgresql, locust

I am encountering an issue with Python Locust where tasks seem to be blocked when using the pyodbc library, but interestingly, the same tasks work fine when using pyodbc within a ThreadPool. I've tested this behavior with both SQL Server and PostgreSQL databases and arrived at the same conclusion, suggesting that the issue lies within Locust itself rather than the database or pyodbc.

Locust application:

```
import logging
import random
import sys
import time

import pyodbc
from gevent import killall
from locust import task, User, TaskSet, events

# SQL Server Connection Details
server = 'localhost'
database = 'test'
username = 'test'
password = 'test'
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
connection_string = f"DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}"

count = 0
running_greenlets = set()
stop_event = None

table_name = f"SampleTable_{int(time.time())}"


class SampleTaskSet(TaskSet):

    def __init__(self, parent: User):
        super().__init__(parent)
        global count
        count = count + 1
        self.counter = count

    @task
    def execute_query(self):
        global stop_event
        if stop_event and stop_event.is_set():
            logging.info("Stop event set. Exiting task.")
            return

        logging.info("User {} started".format(self.counter))
        global table_name
        query = "select * from {}".format(table_name)
        conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, host=server, Database=database, UID=username,
                              PWD=password, Trusted_Connection='no')
        logging.info("User {} connection established".format(self.counter))
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        try:
            logging.info("User %s Executing Query %s ", self.counter, query)

            # Doesn't block task
            # sleep_in_secs = random.randint(5, 10)
            # time.sleep(sleep_in_secs)

            # Blocks task
            cursor.execute(query)
            rows = cursor.fetchall()
            resp_len = len(rows)
            logging.info("User %s completed Query", self.counter)

        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            logging.info("KeyboardInterrupt caught in task")
            if stop_event:
                stop_event.set()
            raise

        finally:
            cursor.close()
            conn.close()


class TestUser(User):
    tasks = [SampleTaskSet]


def on_locust_stop(*args, **kwargs):
    logging.info("Stopping Locust due to signal")
    killall(running_greenlets)
    sys.exit()


@events.test_start.add_listener
def prep_data(environment, **kwargs):
    global table_name

    conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, host=server, Database=database, UID=username, PWD=password,
                          Trusted_Connection='no', autocommit=True)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    logging.info("Creating table %s", table_name)
    try:
        create_table_query = f"CREATE TABLE {table_name} (id INT, name VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255))"
        cursor.execute(create_table_query)
        logging.info("Created table %s", table_name)
        logging.info("Loading data to table %s", table_name)

        for i in range(100_000):
            insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (id, name, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
            cursor.execute(insert_query, (i + 1, f"Name {i + 1}", f"email_{i + 1}@example.com"))
        logging.info("Loaded data to table %s", table_name)

    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

Execution command:

> locust -f db_locust.py --headless -u10 -r10 --host=localhost

Sample log:

```
[2024-03-23 01:27:35,156] machine/INFO/root: Loaded data to table SampleTable_1711171627
[2024-03-23 01:27:35,156] machine/INFO/locust.runners: Ramping to 10 users at a rate of 10.00 per second
[2024-03-23 01:27:35,157] machine/INFO/locust.runners: All users spawned: {"TestUser": 10} (10 total users)
[2024-03-23 01:27:35,157] machine/INFO/root: User 1 started
[2024-03-23 01:27:35,158] machine/INFO/root: User 1 connection established
[2024-03-23 01:27:35,158] machine/INFO/root: User 1 Executing Query select * from SampleTable_1711171627
[2024-03-23 01:27:35,344] machine/INFO/root: User 1 completed Query
[2024-03-23 01:27:35,353] machine/INFO/root: User 2 started
[2024-03-23 01:27:35,354] machine/INFO/root: User 2 connection established
[2024-03-23 01:27:35,355] machine/INFO/root: User 2 Executing Query select * from SampleTable_1711171627
[2024-03-23 01:27:35,537] machine/INFO/root: User 2 completed Query
```

**Expectation**: User x Executing Query at the same time.

Similar version using threadpool,

```
import random
import time

import pyodbc
import concurrent.futures
import logging

# Configure logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(message)s')

num_threads = 10
# SQL Server Connection Details
server = 'localhost'
database = 'test'
username = 'test'
password = 'test'
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
connection_string = f"DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}"

count = 0
table_name = f"SampleTable_{int(time.time())}"

# Function to execute SELECT query
def run_query(user_id):
    logging.info("User {} started".format(user_id))
    global table_name
    query = "select * from {}".format(table_name)
    conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, host=server, Database=database, UID=username,
                          PWD=password, Trusted_Connection='no')
    logging.info("User {} connection established".format(user_id))
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        logging.info("User %s Executing Query %s ", user_id, query)

        # Doesn't block task
        # sleep_in_secs = random.randint(5, 10)
        # time.sleep(sleep_in_secs)

        # Blocks task
        cursor.execute(query)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        resp_len = len(rows)
        logging.info("User %s completed Query", user_id)

    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()

def prep_data():
    global table_name

    conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, host=server, Database=database, UID=username, PWD=password,
                          Trusted_Connection='no', autocommit=True)
    cursor = conn.cursor()

    logging.info("Creating table %s", table_name)
    create_table_query = f"CREATE TABLE {table_name} (id INT, name VARCHAR(255), email VARCHAR(255))"
    cursor.execute(create_table_query)
    logging.info("Created table %s", table_name)
    logging.info("Loading data to table %s", table_name)

    for i in range(100_000):
        insert_query = f"INSERT INTO {table_name} (id, name, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)"
        cursor.execute(insert_query, (i + 1, f"Name {i + 1}", f"email_{i + 1}@example.com"))
    logging.info("Loaded data to table %s", table_name)

    cursor.close()
    conn.close()

# Create ThreadPoolExecutor
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=num_threads) as executor:
    prep_data()
    # Submit tasks to the executor
    futures = [executor.submit(run_query, user_id) for user_id in range(1, num_threads + 1)]

    # Wait for tasks to complete and log completion
    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
        logging.info("Task has completed.")
```

Any help or feedback would be appreciated. If the issue is with pyodbc or getting a connection, it should have been blocking in threadpool which isn't. Can anyone shed some light on how to work around locust issue getting blocked? I have also tried with sleep statements in locust where it doesn't get blocked. It seems a combination of locust with pyodbc which seems to have an issue.

Tried with two versions - locust, threadpool to see if it is reproducible in threadpool. Threadpool version works as expected.

Edit:
Tried with gevent monkey-patching and doesn't work for pyodbc as the cursor.execute() blocks the greenlet.

```
"""Spawn multiple workers and wait for them to complete"""

import logging

import gevent
from gevent import monkey

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

monkey.patch_all(sys=True)

import pyodbc

# Setting up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# SQL Server Connection Details
server = 'localhost'
database = 'test'
username = 'test'
password = 'test'
driver = 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server'
connection_string = f"DRIVER={driver};SERVER={server};DATABASE={database};UID={username};PWD={password}"
count = 0
# 1m rows table
table_name = "SampleTable_1711329791"


def run_query(user_id, query):
    logger.info('User %d started %s' % (user_id, query))
    conn = pyodbc.connect(driver=driver, host=server, Database=database, UID=username,
                          PWD=password, Trusted_Connection='no')
    logging.info("User {} connection established".format(user_id))
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    try:
        logging.info("User %s Executing Query %s ", user_id, query)

        # Doesn't block task
        # sleep_in_secs = random.randint(5, 10)
        # time.sleep(sleep_in_secs)

        # Blocks task
        cursor.execute(query)
        rows = cursor.fetchall()
        resp_len = len(rows)
        logging.info("User %s completed Query", user_id)

    finally:
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()


jobs = [gevent.spawn(run_query, user_id, "select * from {}".format(table_name)) for user_id in range(1, 10)]

gevent.wait(jobs)
```

Comment: It looks like you're having a static method that creates connection meaning the conn is shared by all threads which is wrong since usually only one query can be ran at the same time per connection

Comment: Ok, updated inline to create connection under the task decorator. Still executing sequentially. Updated code above. Even if I go by your logic, I had log statements to print "User x started" - expecting this to print simultaneously but didn't. It means that conn.execute is blocking the entire greenlet. Tried with connection pool object by pre-creating > 10 for user count of 10 and it still was executing serially.

Comment: hmm, i don't know, it seems like connection is a red herring. what happens if you just create 100 tasks that sleeps for random times? Do they get interleaved. Ie, remove all connection stuff

Comment: They get executed simultaneously which is the expectation. Which lib should I raise the issue? Locust or pyodbc?

Comment: Import locust first. Gevent (on which locust is built) needs to patch io calls, and it needs to patch them as early as possible

Comment: Tried the change and still occurs serially.

Comment: @Cyberwiz - Got rid of all gevent import. Sadly, it blocks for gevent monkey-patching :(. Added more detail to the thread.

Comment: Aha. Maybe pyodbc doesnt work with gevent? Then you cant really use it with locust I’m afraid :(